# How does .htaccess behave when located in directory above doc root

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following rules in my .htacess file. They work perfectly fine as is, but I have several doc roots which I would like to apply the same rules to, all in the same parent directory. Is this possible with .htaccess?

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/some/path($|/)
RewriteRule (.*) /some/path/$1 [L]

FallbackResource /some/path/index.html
```

I know .htaccess is somewhat relative to the directory they're in, so I'm thinking I need to modify these somehow.

The end result from just moving it directly to the parent directory is everything returns the contents of /some/path/index.html

Comment: Just use the actual http server configuration instead. That is more effective than distributed configuration file (".htaccess") anyway.

Comment: Because of the way my hosting provider set things up, using .htaccess might be easer in this case.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone this helps, I accomplished this by adding it to the "post virtual hosts" section of my main apache config.

```
<Directory "/home/*/parentdirectory/*">
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteRule !/some/path/ /some/path%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

  FallbackResource /some/path/index.html
</Directory>
```